# Risks for not doing proper unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have asked a unit testing practical question previously ([Unit testing: how to test methods with a lot of underlying objects and business logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294861/unit-testing-how-to-test-methods-with-a-lot-of-underlying-objects-and-business)), and I need to open another subject on the same piece of code.

The question is what if I disregard what everybody tells me, and I proceed to "unit-test"-ing that `MoveElementAtIndex` method (which moves Products within a product collection) without any stress about the underlying calls and usages of other classes. I can just instantiate a new collection of products and test that they move around correctly, right?

This is not unit testing, I know. It's not integration testing either. 
It's hybrid, and what would you say it is wrong with that? It would still help me to avoid problems. Or wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing very wrong about it, but you could easily make it a real unittest, if your collection was not concrete products, but interfaces of products. By doing this, you make sure, that the outcome of your test does not depend on the implementation issues in your product objects. This makes the test cleaner, and your code more dependable.

And by the way: There are no hybrids between unit and integration tests. What You have is an integration test. Only if you replace all external dependecies with stubs or mocks, you can call it a unit test.

Comment: Most probably I could, but the problem is that it's just one method out of 5000 which are at least as coupled as it.